# Access DOM inside iFrame using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ember.js

I am trying to access a DOM element from my main page and want to update the CSS. I use the following;

```
var myIframeContainerEl = $('#myIframeContainerEl');
myIframeContainerEl.contents().find(".required").css("color", "#f0f0f0");
```

This is not working for some reason.
While it is able to find "myIframeContainerEl", for some reasons, "myIframeContainerEl.contents()" shows a length of 0.
Is the above not the correct way of doing it?

Also, just to add, I am using this in my Ember project and use it within didTransition hook and inside "afterRender"
So the element is present when I am trying to access.

Answer (score 2):

`iframe`s don't have contents in the document they appear in. But they have a [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property that refers to the document that they do have contents in. You can tell jQuery to look in that document like this:

```
var frameDocument = $('#myIframeContainerEl')[0].contentDocument;
$(frameDocument).find(".required").css("color", "#f0f0f0");
```

*(Note that this assumes the `iframe`'s contents are from the same origin, otherwise the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids access unless [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) or similar is used.)*

Comment: Thanks...It might be a CORS thing...So my main page is on http://myMainSite.MyDomain.com , while the iframe is rendered from http://myIframe.MyDomain.com ....Not sure if that is considered cross-origin and would not work ?

Comment: Different sub domains are considered as different origins. The second [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) sums it up pretty nicely.

Comment: @testndtv - It's not *just* an SOP thing, you do have to adjust the code as shown above. In the particular case of a subdomain, you *might* be okay with just [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain), but CORS would be the better way.

Comment: So when you say document.domain...I am not sure what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: @testndtv - That's what the link was for. :-)

Comment: Oh k...I thought there is some workaround even if it is not same domain...

Comment: @testndtv - Ah, yes, sorry, I missed that your parent was on a subdomain as well. I don't think `document.domain` helps there. It would only help (and again, it's deprecated anyway) if the parent were `example.com` and the iframe were `frame.example.com` or similar (the iframe could say `document.domain = "example.com"`).